# Facebook Share: can not get value `og:image` and `og:title`

Tags: facebook-share

I don't know why Facebook Share not getting value of `og:image`, `og:title` of my website while I inspect element I see everything correct.

**This is facebook debug**:

Attributes are inferred: The `og:image` attribute must be explicitly provided, even if it is possible to derive value from other tags.

Lack of assets

The following required assets are missing: `og:url`, `og:type`, `og:title`, `og:image`, `og:description`, `fb:app_id`.

Bad response code

URL returned a bad response response code

[image: Image1]

**These are elements on my website**

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vnlovepet.com/blog/huan-luyen-cho-alaska-nhu-the-nao-cho-dung-58">
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Huấn luyện chó Alaska như thế nào cho đúng?">
<meta property="og:description" content="Huấn luyện chó Alasla là một trong những sở thích của nhiều người, nhưng họ lại chưa biết cách huấn luyện thế nào cho đúng.">
```

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look, how exactly Facebook's **scraper** sees your URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvnlovepet.com%2Fblog%2Fhuan-luyen-cho-alaska-nhu-the-nao-cho-dung-58

There are errors dumped into HTML and that's the reason of your issue.

Comment: how do you see that. when i access http://vnlovepet.com/blog/huan-luyen-cho-alaska-nhu-the-nao-cho-dung-58 I don't see anything

Comment: Have a look at link I provided. There are errors. I reckon your code tries to parse user agent header, but Facebook scrapper has its own.

Comment: i use jenssegers/agent to detect device